# Combobox UI resetting itself after internal update during selection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox bound to an `Enum`. When I click on a new value in my combobox, I'm generating a message to an attached device and getting a response back. I want to file whatever value is received back.

My regular-old bound property looks like this:

```
private Enum enumValue;

public Enum EnumValue
{
   get => enumValue;
   set
   {
     if (enumValue != value)
     {
         enumValue = value;
         sendToDevice();
     }

   }

}
```

My update from device looks like this:

```
    public void SetValueFromDevice(string valueFromDevice)
    {
       enumValue = (Enum)Enum.Parse(EnumType, valueFromDevice);
       RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(EnumValue));
    }
```

Note that I'm setting the private variable `enumValue` directly because I don't want to trigger another outgoing message to my device if I don't need to.

Here's the situation: Let's say I have an enum that looks like this:

```
    public enum Sources
    {
        Off,
        Low,
        Mid,
        Hi
    }
```

The firmware I've written doesn't like the value of low on certain versions on the device. Instead, it'll reply back with whatever the current value is. I want to file that back to the combo box instead of showing the incorrect value to the user.

Now, what seems to happen is after I click on the combobox item, it sends a message to my device, gets the response, and then files it back appropriately. I can step through and see the combobox doing the "get" after I call `RaisePropertyChanged`, but it doesn't seem to be updating the selected item at all.

I can call `SetValueFromDevice`  and that always works, so it seems like it's the UI acting up.

I even attempted to totally force it with

```
 control.DropDownClosed += new EventHandler(SourceBox_DropDownClosed);
 ....
    private void SourceBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox box = sender as ComboBox;
      box.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty).UpdateTarget();
    }
```

...and that did nothing.
What am I doing wrong here? Is there any way to set the item of the combobox during the item selection interaction?

Comment: Enums are value types and therefore can't be null, there are ways though around that like `?` and `Nullable`...

Comment: I just removed that, good call, it wasn't doing anything anyway (what I was trying to fix with that was fixed in a different way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: I needed to make my  `sendToDevice()` call asyncronous, because I'd be triggering the RaisePropertyChanged twice in the same process, and it'd only "see" the first one.

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => sendToDevice());
```